# Stored procedure not found using vb.net and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

It is my vb.net code to execute a stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
Dim _command As New SqlCommand("xxx", sqlConnection)
_command.commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

sqlDataReader = _command.ExecuteReader()
```

but it gives this error

> No se encontró el procedimiento almacenado 'xxx'."

I also tried `New SqlCommand("dbo.xxx", sqlConnection)` but got the same error

Where do I have to store my stored procedure? My stored procedure folder on database is empty because I don't find it when I want to save the xxx.sql file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the stored procedure inside your database.

This is usually done using the Sql Server Management Studio or the Server Explorer window inside Visual Studio.

In SSMS open a new query window, select the correct database and paste the code of your storedprocedure. Then hit the exlamation mark to execute the code that creates the stored procedure

In Server Explorer open your connection, right click on the StoredProcedure node and select Create New Stored Procedure. Replace the template code with your own and then hit the Save button

Now you have the stored procedure inside your database and you could call it as you have already done

Comment: I did something like that and stored the xxx.sql file on a folder named `projects`, I thought I havd to stored on `storedprocedure` folder

Comment: @Andres: just **storing** a `.sql` file in a folder doesn't work - you'll have to open the `.sql` file that contains your stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio and **execute it** to create the stored procedure inside your database

Comment: The .sql file contains the code that creates or updates the stored procedure. If you open it with any text editor you could see at the beginning of the file the command CREATE PROCEDURE (or ALTER PROCEDURE if you are changing an existing SP)

Comment: @marc_s I had done that. Finally it works, I guess my stored procedure was wrong because I worked when I created again. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

have you created a stored procedure? In SQL Management Studio,

```
create proc xxx
as
select 'hola'
union
select 'andres'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a stored procedure first. Open SQL Server then New Query, type in your Stored procedure. Please find below an example from the northwind database:

```
USE [Northwind]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Sales by Year]    Script Date: 11/29/2013 15:33:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[Sales by Year] 
    @Beginning_Date DateTime, @Ending_Date DateTime AS
SELECT Orders.ShippedDate, Orders.OrderID, "Order Subtotals".Subtotal, DATENAME(yy,ShippedDate) AS Year
FROM Orders INNER JOIN "Order Subtotals" ON Orders.OrderID = "Order Subtotals".OrderID
WHERE Orders.ShippedDate Between @Beginning_Date And @Ending_Date
```

In your code you can do the following:

```
    // instance of the sql connection class
    SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString); 

    // open a connection
    objConnection.Open();

    // Fire Command Object
    SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, objConnection);

    // new instance of the data set class
    DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable();

    // new instance of the sqldataadpater class
    SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);

    // type of command
    objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // fill the dataset
    objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataTable);

    //close the connection
    objConnection.Close();

    //return the dataset
    return objDataTable;
```

Answer (score -1):

After that, the developer will need to individually map fields to  columns in the result set while mapping fields to parameters in the stored procedures.  There is an easier way.  I think it is long over due for Microsoft to release a System.Persistence namespace.